# How to add ' ' to php variable in query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have this simple query

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM `client` where name= ".$user_name;
```

Now the query is printed

```
select id from client where name = Bob;
```

when in fact it should be

```
select id from client where name = 'Bob';
```

how can i add single quotes in the php variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Your code is prone to sql injection

Comment: Its okay to injection its just a simple query

Comment: presumably `name` contains a `string` rather than a `number` so you would, at the very least, require quotes around the value in the sql statement.  As for `Its okay to injection its just a simple query` - better to learn the correct way and apply that for every occasion than use vulnerable code

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i know how to protect against sql injection but this is for a work that im not being valuated a lot so i dont care for the security]

Comment: Seems like a good career decision to deliberately introduce flaws into your code '-)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it is a good career decision when the company doesnt respect the workers why should the workers respect the company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I warned you and you are fine to sql injection then just try this.

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM `client` where name= '".$user_name."'";
```

Comment: or just  this 
$query = "SELECT id FROM `client` where name= '$user_name' ";